# Strange error while trying to create a Web Service consumer on Lotus Domino Designer (8.5.3)

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-notes

I am stuck on a problem that I cannot find answer, no matter how hard I google it.
I am trying to create a WS consumer on Lotus Domino Designer. The version is 8.5.3.

I have already tried with three different WS and answer was always the same.
Here it is :

```
WebServiceEngineFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException faultSubcode:  faultString: Error connecting to &apos;www.webservicex.net&apos; on port &apos;80&apos;, You must enable the Notes TCPIP port. faultActor:  faultNode:  faultDetail:   Error connecting to 'www.webservicex.net' on port '80', You must enable the Notes TCPIP port.
                at lotus.domino.axis.InternalFault.makeFault(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.websvc.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at NET.webserviceX.www.AngleUnitSoapStub.changeAngleUnit(AngleUnitSoapStub.java:11)
                at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: Error connecting to 'www.webservicex.net' on port '80', You must enable the Notes TCPIP port.
                at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.NotesSocket.openConnection(Native Method)
                at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.NotesSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(Unknown Source)
                ... 15 more
```

What I did was importing the wsdl from a very simple web service (Web Service X), www.webservicex.net just for the sake of testing, to a Web Service consumer. I imported it into my Java Agent and tried to call one method. The agent code looks like this,  I think it could hardly be simpler :

```
import lotus.domino.*;

import NET.webserviceX.www.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
          AngleUnitSoap stub;
          double retVal;

          System.out.println("Start");
          AngleUnitLocator locator = new AngleUnitLocator();
          stub = locator.getAngleUnitSoap();
          retVal = stub.changeAngleUnit(180,Angles.degrees, Angles.radians);
          System.out.println("end");
      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

I tried with a couple more ws and result was the same. I do declare that I cannot understand the TCPIP error. The port is open on preferences section in Lotus Domino Designer. And, again, for test sake, I wrote a small java agent that just retrieves the html of a web page and it did successfully. Unless I am mstaken, I gues this means communication is working OK. I really dont know what I am doing wrong. I am probably missing something obvious.
Thank you so much in advance for your kind help. I tried to narrow down my question as much as possible, but feel free to ask additional info,
I deeply appreciate your kind help on this

With my kindest Regards,
Carlos

Comment: What's your endpoint in the WSDL file?

Comment: Also if you open your consumer XXXService class, it will show you auto generated sample code to instantiate your stub (looks incorrect above).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Angle Unit mention in your source code I believe the Web Service you are trying to consume is the [Convert Angle](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=35&CATID=13) sample.

Looking at the [WSDL File](http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAngle.asmx?WSDL), at the very top you can see the following:

```
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
```

This means the web service is using SOAP1.2. Domino only supports SOAP1.1 as detailed on the [infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WEB_SERVICES_WEB.html).

If you want to create your own there is a [tutorial](https://ibm.biz/BdRrcq) on the Appdev wiki.

Comment: Hi, Simon. I followed the tutorial and I got the same issue on LotusScript. I discovered that the problem was related to the fact that I had Domino Designer set to Offline on right lower corner. Thank you so much for your help